# Can't prevent keyboard input on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, mobile

so I want to prevent keyboard input when the user goes over a character limit in a contentEditable p tag:

```
<p autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter text..." class="entry__text"></p>


$('.entry__text').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.target.innerHTML.length > 10) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // return false;
    }
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

Either e.preventDefault() or return false; doesn't work. The condition is met, but keys still get written to the p tag. It does work on everything else except on newest Chrome on mobile Androids.

I tested in on a little bit older version (Chrome 40.0.2357.93 and then 51.xx), and it did prevent input.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shriek/H7h87/) might help you to solve the issue.

Comment: Your solution places the cursor at the begining of the string, after character limit is reached. It's confusing. Is there any way to just prevent the cursor from moving to the begining? @androidOnHigh

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes below to your code. I have added the maxlength attribute to your tag.

```
<p autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter text..." maxlength="10" class="entry__text"></p>
```

Add the JavaScript code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var limitNum = 10;
  $("p[contenteditable='true'][maxlength]").on('keydown paste', function (event) {
     var cntMaxLength = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));

     if ($(this).text().length === cntMaxLength && event.keyCode != 8) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
  });
});
```

For your reference, check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17943/).

Comment: Please may I know whether your issue has been resolved or not yet?