# Prevent text keyboard input on Android/chrome mobile [web]

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a textarea with keyDown listener

```
<textarea onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}></textarea>
```

And the handleKeyDown function:

```
const handleKeyDown = event => event.preventDefault()
```

When I typing from windows PC, Chrome Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit) everything works perfect: text is not appearing in textarea.

When I typing from mac, chrome 90 everything works perfect too.

But when I grab my Android Phone (Samsung, Android 11), open Mobile Chrome (90.0.4430.210) and start typing, text IS appearing in textarea. And the worst thing is that the only mention about this bug I found is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151231/cant-prevent-keyboard-input-on-android-chrome), which will be referenced by bots when marking my question as duplicate. There is no answer: maxlength attribute not working anymore.

This is the list of things I tried to prevent mobile chrome from input:

- Maxlength = 0 (no effect at all)
- readOnly (=disabled, I need focus and selection)
- blocking onKeyUp, onKeyPress, onPaste, onCut, onInput

I also tried to manually set value of textarea to '' but if I set a listener which does this, my textarea become completely broken: each time I press key on keyboard, it duplicates all previous content.

My question is **how to prevent input**, maybe there is a hack or trick? Please don't send me to android report forums where this bug may be discussed or another questions...

Comment: `<textarea readonly/>` prevents keyboard but still allows selection on my phone.

Comment: @Keith Can you please tell what is your phone and OS?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Android and tested the readonly here -> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea_readonly

Comment: Version. 90.0.4430.210

Comment: Anyway, I need keyboard to show up so readOnly attribute is not an option here. For now, I placed a fake textarea above the real one. It hides selection cursor but at least works fine.

Comment: Sorry, thought you didn't want the keyboard to appear.  Did you try doing `event.preventDefault` on the change event..?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to see if the events are working when adding eventlisteners. There must be a way to handle key events on Android:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

```
let mytextarea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');

mytextarea.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  console.log(event.code);
});
```

**If this is not working;** you asked for a hack or trick: try the focus and blur events, then you could run a function on interval that clears the textarea. Note that this blocking trick is something that goes against good user experience conventions, so should be considered a hack/trick for sure ;-)

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

```
let int1;

let mytextarea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');

mytextarea.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  clearInterval(int1);
  int1 = setInterval(() => {
    mytextarea.value = '';
  }, 10)
});

mytextarea.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  clearInterval(int1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *event*.**key** or *event*.**code** properties of **keypress** (keyup, keydown) event, I have used *event*.**inputType**, *event*.**data** of **update** event and added few restricting attributes to the input tag to overcome 'smartness' of mobile keyboard app. It is an ugly hack but worked for my purpose.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="inpt" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" ></textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var inpt = document.getElementById('inpt');
inpt.addEventListener('input', do_on_input);

function do_on_input(e) {
  
  if( e.inputType == "insertText"){
    console.log( e.data );
  }
  
  if( e.inputType == "deleteContentBackward"){
    console.log('Backspace');     
  }
  
  if( e.inputType == "insertCompositionText"){
    // without restrictive attribbutes you will need to deal with this type events
  }
  
}
```